# How do I implement abstract classes in C++ while allowing for subclass method calls?

Tags: c++

I made a class called `A` that has a virtual method `do_something`:

```
class A {
  virtual int do_something() = 0;
}
```

`B` subclasses `A`:

```
class B {
  virtual int do_something() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

Somewhere in my main function, I do this.

```
vector<A> arr;
arr.push_back(B());
int val = arr[0].do_something();
```

However, I get a compiler error complaining that `do_something` is a pure virtual function. I believe this is because I declared the vector to contain objects of type `A`, and `A` is an abstract class. The compiler thus doesn't know to look in class `B` to see if `do_something` is define.

Is there a way around this? Can I still store a vector of objects of different types (with a common superclass though that declares a common virtual function)?

Comment: Type slicing. When you put `B` into `vector<A>`, a bus runs over it until it's no longer a `B`. If you need runtime polymorphism, use pointers.

Comment: Actually, it is not that the compiler doesn't know to look in class `B`. The vector contains `A` objects, so `B` doesn't even come into it. Look up "object slicing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring a vector this way:

```
vector<A> arr;
```

You are attempting to create a vector of objects of **direct type** `A`. Not only this would not allow you to store objects of type `B` in there (if `A` were not abstract, you would get [**slicing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), which you certainly don't want), but it also fails to compile because no direct instances of `A` can exist.

What you want here is to store *pointers* to `A` (possibly smart pointers):

```
#include <memory> // For smart pointer classes

vector<shared_ptr<A>> arr;
arr.push_back(make_shared<B>());
int val = arr[0]->do_something();
```

Here I decided to use `shared_ptr`, assuming shared ownership, but if the only owner of the objects is the container `arr`, `unique_ptr` would be a better choice.

Eventually, if you really know what you are doing and you are ready to bear the hassle of automatic memory management, you could use raw pointers, but I discourage you from doing that (you would have to make sure you deallocate with `delete` every object you allocate with `new`):

```
vector<A*> arr;
arr.push_back(new B());
int val = arr[0]->do_something();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way around this? Can I still store a vector of objects of different types (with a common superclass though that declares a common virtual function)?

use smart pointer with std::vector

```
std::vector<std::unique<A>> arr;
arr.emplace_back(new B());
```

OR

```
arr.emplace_back(std::make_shared<B>());
```